# How can I "if check" a template helper and use its return value in template

Tags: meteor

Basically this is my code and it's repeated. It does not work if I use `have_last_attr` 2 times (inside if). How could I manage it ?

```
# .html
{{#if have_last_attr}}
    <h3>Last attribute was {{last_attr}}</h3>
{{/if}}

# .js
Template.game.have_last_attr = function(){
    var game_id = Session.get('current_game'),
        game = Games.findOne(game_id),
        attr = game['last_attr'];

    return TRANSLATE[attr];
};

Template.game.last_attr = function(){
    var game_id = Session.get('current_game'),
        game = Games.findOne(game_id),
        attr = game['last_attr'];

    return TRANSLATE[attr];
};
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `{{#with ...}}` statement ([handlebars doc](http://handlebarsjs.com/#with)). At least this is what I do if I don't want to do things twice...

```
{{#with last_attr}}
   {{#if this}}
       <h3>Last attribute was {{this}}</h3>
   {{/if}}
{{/with}}
```